# How initialize the culture based on language selector value(dropdownlist) on error while logging in using asp.net login control in asp.net 4.0 and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, localization, autopostback

I have created a login page using asp.net login control and I have added a dropdownlist as a language selector (English and French) with autopostback = true. So whenever the value changes in the dropdownlist, the translations of labels etc are retrieved from corresponding resource file. The issue is when there is an error in logging in (entered wrong password) the page changes to English even when the ddl value is French. I am overriding Initialize culture ().
Login.aspx.cs-

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
{
    string language = "E";
     language=  Language.CurrentLanguage;
    if (Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] != null && Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"].Contains("ddlLanguages"))
    {
        language = Request.Form[Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"]];
    }
    if (language == "F")
    {
        language = "fr-CA";
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(language);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(language);
    }
    else
    {
        language = "en-US";
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(language);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(language);
    }
}
```

Comment: The note on the MSDN [Login.LoggedIn Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.loggedin.aspx) might be the problem. `When a user uses the Login control to log in to a Web site, all data in the view state and all post data is lost. Do not perform actions in the LoggedIn event that rely on the view state.`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am overriding the InitializeCulture () of Page event . I am not performing any action related to language selected in LoggedIn event . And this scenario in my problem happens at Login_Error event .

Comment: I managed to do it myself by calling the dropdownlist_SelectedIndexChanged().